# How to do a/b testing on a page that requires a session?

Tags: ab-testing

I am trying to do A/B testing for the first time. I am using VWO and the page i'm trying to setup testing for requires a session to reach. A user hits the landing page and then signs up and is redirected to the page I am trying to test. Is it possible to setup A/B testing for such a page?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: sure. say my landing page is www.example.com. I am trying to test www.example.com/members. But the members page is only accessible once an account is created. If i place the www.example.com/members URL in the URLS to test on the VWO website, it displays the landing page www.example.com.